# Is Java needed to use Red5

Tags: java, flash, video, streaming, red5

I'm working on a Flash project and someone recommended Red5 as a media streaming server.

Do I need to know java to use build applications that use Red5 as their server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the project.

Red5 will be used for the server-side part and it comes with a number of features out of the box.

If for example it's just a simple video on demand with RTMP streaming, you can do it with Red5 and the oflaDemo plugin which has already and is very easy without touching java, but if you need something more complex for server-side (for example a playlist, use of cookies etc), then you'll need to know java and even then it will be pretty difficult as there isn't very good documentation for Red5 out there.

But you can control many things from the client side with flash.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably learn it, or at least have minor experience with it.  You can write stuff for Red5 in other languages, but they all require SOME knowledge of Java.  For instance, to use JRuby, you still have to compile a java class that calls the JRuby methods.  Ridiculous, but true!  I have a sample JRuby project here: http://github.com/bbhoss/red5-jruby

Comment: Is actionscript or flex one of those languages that would suffice for writing for Red5? I really don't want to have to learn Java just to use Red5.

Comment: According to their docs, you can use: JavaScript, Groovy, Beanshell, JRuby, and Jython for scripting, but I think you have to use the method I used in my sample project.